# Why eth.contract.Transfer returns only select transactions?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, erc20

I am trying to get all transfer events of an ERC-20 token. But using web3.contract.event.eventName returns only select events of some 12 hours ago. 
Where I am going wrong?

Current Block is : 8514062; But latest transaction I got is of block 8510432

```
tokenContract.events.Transfer({
    fromBlock: 8510000,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}, function (error, events) {
}).on('data', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
})
```

Address I am following: 0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52

Last transaction I am getting:

```
{ address: '0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52',
    blockHash: '0x8c822492376ee6bab76b8534f067631c2b149568c030953378cbc45733609528',
    blockNumber: 8510432,
    logIndex: 54,
    removed: false,
    transactionHash: '0x7a416f681333e5147268913382ad7995b372151a7716544e9a97fef4e23d3974',
    transactionIndex: 24,
    transactionLogIndex: '0x1',
    type: 'mined',
    id: 'log_51f5ea6e',
    returnValues: 
     Result {
       '0': '0xEee90e509a639E95E3BB502B17A0eEd6E014BFc0',
       '1': '0x751b934E7496E437503D74D0679A45E49C0B7071',
       '2': '2960491170000000000',
       from: '0xEee90e509a639E95E3BB502B17A0eEd6E014BFc0',
       to: '0x751b934E7496E437503D74D0679A45E49C0B7071',
       value: '2960491170000000000' },
    event: 'Transfer',
    signature: '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
    raw: 
     { data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002915c708a487d400',
       topics: [Array] } }
```